# Location of the struct when only the location of a member is given

Tags: c, memory-management, struct

Let us assume there is a struct with multiple members. The struct members are initialized with some values. The memory location of a specific member is given. Assume that you don't know the other members, their types, the ordering of members etc. Is there a way to know the memory location of the struct itself?

Is this problem called a specific name?

Comment: Do you know the struct type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Everyone I found the answer this

Cast a null pointer to the struct. You can get the offset by casting the resulting address(Offset) to a char*

```
(char *)(&((struct *)0)->member))
```

You could do any type*. But char* guarantees it's always the word size.

This should be how offsetof() is written as well

Answer (score 4):

If you know the name of the struct, simply use [offsetof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof)

```
struct my_struct {
    const char *name;
    struct list_node list;
};

int main() {
    struct my_struct t;
    struct list_node* pl = &t.list;
    size_t offset = offsetof(struct my_struct, list); //here
    struct my_struct* pt = (struct my_struct*)((unsigned char*)pl-offset); //and here
}
```

If `offsetof` is not viable for what you're doing, then no, there's no other way.  Offsetof can alternatively be written in standard C, but there's absolutely no good reason to do that.

Comment: One could have a header byte and hope that byte is unique within the struct.

Comment: @Anycorn: One could hope

Comment: `pl` should be cast to `unsigned char *` for pointer arithmetic to work in the last line.

Comment: @AlokSinghal: Thanks.  `char` is shorter, but my knowledge of C may not be as deep as yours.  Is `char` wrong or simply less clear?

Comment: You can use `char *` here. I almost always use `unsigned char *` when I am dealing with "raw data" but since here you're only doing pointer arithmetic, `char *` should be fine.  I think. :-)

Comment: `char *` is fine. Also `my_strict` has a typo

Comment: `offsetof` is not required, people have been doing this long before it existed.  It just takes some pointer math.  See `__containerof()` in ArtemB's post

Comment: All that `__containerof()` implementation does is the exact same thing as this answer, except it uses gcc's extension `__builtin_offsetof` in place of the standard, and better, `offsetof` (better for users, that is - gcc actually implements the standard `offsetof` using `__builtin_offsetof`, which is obviously fine).

Comment: That's not true. Check my answer below
 Cast a null pointer to the struct. You can get the offset by casting the resulting address(Offset) to a char*

(char *)(&((struct *)0)->member))
You could do any type*. But char* guarantees it's always the word size.

This should be how offsetof() is written as well

Answer (score 2):

If you know the structure type, then all you need is an offset of the field within the structure, subtract it from the member address and typecast result to pointer to the structure. For a practical implementation see [FreeBSD's implementation of __containerof()](http://bxr.su/FreeBSD/sys/sys/cdefs.h#471).

Comment: The above are correct. However, I suggest that do to the  pointer arithmetic that you use a  char *, and use a negative array subscript rather than converting pointers to integers and subtracting.

Comment: @user3344003 Unlike math on integers, you are not guaranteed that sizeof(char) == 1 and therefore doing math on (char*) is less portable than doing math on properly sized integers. You need to cast in any case.

Comment: `sizeof(char) == 1` is guaranteed by the C standard.

Comment: Yes, `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition. All the other sizes are multiples of it. Furthermore, from C11 6.3.2.3.8: "When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object", so the arithmetic itself is also well-defined by the standard.

Comment: Ah. When will they stop messing my my favorite assembler^W language? Nobody cares about 18-bit machines operating on ternary logic these days. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setun

Comment: Even with an 18-bit `char`, `sizeof(char)` is 1. :-)

Comment: Well, when we're all able to get our hands on quantum computers, we may find a happy use for `CHAR_BIT` again. Except I have a sneaking feeling its value will be indeterminate...

Comment: That depends on the meaning of `1` and `is`. :-)

Comment: @ArtemB: C has never supported ternary, which always kind of irked me.  C requires bits officially.